# How do I compare Data which are Inside a structure?

Tags: data-structures, structure, racket

lets say I have this:
        (define-struct person (age sex code))
        (define-struct subject (person times))

```
    (define P1 (make-subject (make-person 19 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
    (define P2 ...)))
    (define P3 ...)))
    ...

    (define subjects P1 P2 ... )
```

I want to find out the lowest age of a person in the list subjects.

I can't figure out how to implement something like this. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [argmin](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._argmin%29%29).

```
(define-struct person (age sex code) #:transparent)
(define-struct subject (person times)  #:transparent)

(define P1 (make-subject (make-person 19 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
(define P2 (make-subject (make-person 31 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
(define P3 (make-subject (make-person 14 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
(define P4 (make-subject (make-person 45 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
(define P5 (make-subject (make-person 56 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
(define P6 (make-subject (make-person 20 'f     'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))

(define subjects (list P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6))

(define (min-age l)
  (argmin (lambda (s) (person-age (subject-person s))) l))

> (min-age subjects)
(subject (person 14 'f 'OM29Q) '(299 194 242 303 243))
> (person-age (subject-person (min-age subjects)))
14
```